# Multiple SQLite Tables not working correctly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am attempting to create two SQLite tables. One that holds "ToDoItem"s and the other holds "DetailItem"s.  When creating them and logging them I get this:

```
   I/todos: [ToDoItem [id=1, toDoItemName=1], ToDoItem [id=2,toDoItemName=2]]
   I/detailitems: [ToDoItem [id=1, toDoItemName=["1.1","1.2","1.3"]], ToDoItem [id=2, toDoItemName=[]]]
```

As you may notice, it seems that both tables contain ToDoItems but one is supposed to be holding "DetailItem"s.
Here is the code of my DatabaseHelper:

```
    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";

public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String TABLE_DETAILS = "details";

//common columns
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
//todoitem columns
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
//detailitem columns
public static final String COLUMN_DETAILID = "detail_id";
public static final String COLUMN_DETAILNAME = "detailname";

private static final String TODOTABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " (" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
        ");";
private static final String DETAILTABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DETAILS + " (" +
        COLUMN_DETAILID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_DETAILNAME + " TEXT " +
        ");";


//We need to pass database information along to superclass
public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(TODOTABLE);
    db.execSQL(DETAILTABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DETAILS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//--------TODOITEM METHODS-------//
//Add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(ToDoItem product){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.getToDoItemName());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
}
/*public void deleteProduct(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
}*/

public List getAllToDos() {
    List toDoItems = new LinkedList();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // parse all results
    ToDoItem toDoItem = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            toDoItem = new ToDoItem();
            toDoItem.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            toDoItem.setToDoItemName(cursor.getString(1));

            toDoItems.add(toDoItem);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return toDoItems;
}

public int updateProduct(ToDoItem toDoItem, String v1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, v1);

    // updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_PRODUCTS, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(toDoItem.getId()) });

    db.close();
    return i;
}

//----------DETAILITEM methods-----------//

public void addDetailItemName(DetailItem detailItem){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_DETAILNAME, detailItem.getDetailText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_DETAILS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public void deleteDetailItem(String detailName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_DETAILS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DETAILNAME + "=\"" + detailName + "\";");
}

public List getAllDetailItems() {
    List detailItems = new LinkedList();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DETAILS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // parse all results
    DetailItem detailItem = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            detailItem = new DetailItem();
            detailItem.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            detailItem.setDetailText(cursor.getString(1));

            detailItems.add(detailItem);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return detailItems;
}

public int updateDetailItem(DetailItem detailItem, String v1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_DETAILNAME, v1);

    // updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_DETAILS, values, COLUMN_DETAILID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(detailItem.getId()) });

    db.close();
    return i;
}
    }
```

Code for DetailItem:

```
public class DetailItem {
public String _detailText;
private int _id;

public DetailItem(){}

public int getId() {
    return _id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this._id = id;
}

public DetailItem(String detailText){
    this._detailText = detailText;
}

public String getDetailText() {
    return _detailText;
}

public void setDetailText(String detailText) {
    this._detailText = detailText;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "ToDoItem [id=" + _id + ", toDoItemName=" + _detailText + "]";

}
```

}

Code for ToDoItem:

```
public class ToDoItem {
private String _toDoItemName;
private int _id;

public ToDoItem(){}

public ToDoItem(String toDoItemName){
    this._toDoItemName = toDoItemName;
}

public int getId() {
    return _id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this._id = id;
}

public void setToDoItemName(String toDoItemName) {
    this._toDoItemName = toDoItemName;
}

public String getToDoItemName(){
    return _toDoItemName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "ToDoItem [id=" + _id + ", toDoItemName=" + _toDoItemName + "]";

}
```

}

Comment: can you post your code for `ToDoItem` and `DetailItem`?

Comment: Added both the code for ToDoItem and DetailItem. Feel free to ask for anything else if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `ToDoItem` and `DetailItem` classes are both reporting `ToDoItem` in their `toString()` methods. Try differentiating those and then check to see that your log output accurately reflects that change.

Comment: I appreciate it.  An obvious, easy fix but sometimes it just takes another person's eyes to catch it.  Thanks again.